# What increases the BIOS Time? Windows 10

Tags: windows, boot, bios, services

I recently reset my Windows 10 PC. The 'last BIOS time' when I checked first was 1.8 seconds (I kept only necessary startup items and services enabled). I used to check it frequently as I was installing more programs until recently it jumped to 2.4 seconds (after installing Adobe Photoshop I believe). I disabled all the newly appeared startup program and services. Now it reached 1.9 seconds. I just want to know where I lost the 0.1 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://www.howtogeek.com/265623/what-is-last-bios-time-in-the-windows-task-manager/ this value is the time before booting windows, so it is not relevant for this value which software is installed or autostarting.

I would consider 100ms as a possible variation/error of measurement. The 0.6 seconds may be caused by more devices that were connected to your computer or just by a device that took slightly longer to answer the UEFI/BIOS request, for example because it did a self check.

Comment: But I don't connect any device other than a wired mouse to my laptop. Then what might have caused the jump?